# Regex splitting token into two separate pieces

Tags: python, regex

My Regex isn't matching this entire token as one. I can't figure out why. It's storing the 0 in another index in the list but I need x-0 to match as one token.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\b\w\D\-\d\W\b)')

test = 'x-0'
matches = pattern.finditer(test)
tokens = []
for match in matches:
    tokens.append(match.group(0))
```

Output

```
['x-', '0']
```

Comment: You need `r'\b\w-\d\b'`. Or, `r'\b\w+-\d+\b'`

Comment: I do not get that output.

Comment: `\w\D` matches two characters, but you don't have two characters before the `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you added `\D` and `\W` to match the pattern above.
There is no non-digit character after `x` which is not `-` and there is no non-alphanumeric character after `0` so you might want to omit `\D` and `\W`. Another option is to use the asterisk (`*`) as below.
Let me know whether this helps:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\b\w(\D*)-\d(\W*)\b)')

test = 'x-0'
tokens = pattern.findall(test)
```

Comment: Use triple backticks around the code block, not triple quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried with backticks but for some reason it didn't work :S